# Annyang speech recognition from file

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, annyang

Can you use Annyang.js for speech recognition from files? To be specific, the file would contain simple, predefined commands like simple words, alphabets or digits.

Essentially, what I would like to do is get the input for Annyang from an audio file instead of the microphone. If this is not the right approach, could anyone suggest how this can be done?

Comment: I'm sorry I must have mentioned this - the input is from an audio file. I'll update the question right away.

Comment: Makes more sense then ;-) I think you can't set the input to something else than gUM in the SpeechRecognition API (which annyang does use), so the only workaround would be to use a 'virtual audio input device' and to stream your audio file through this input, making it available as a native input device. Not really convenient for end user ;-) But anyway, since you know your files (do you?) you can simply check the `currentTime` of your media and then trigger actions base on this instead of using the poorly supported SpeechRecognition API.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I found softwares like VB-Audio Virtual Cable and SoundFlower but I would manually need to play each audio file in order to get this done.

Comment: Yep, but once again, you don't really need to do this. I think the easiest is for you to store all occurences of the spoken commands in a text file, with the `currentTime` associated, and then just check while playing the media in your list of commands if some have been said.